# Create multi Jar by for loop task call with gradle

Tags: java, gradle

- In my project, there is a package `com.fool.bar.names`
- under this package, I have 'tom', 'jerry', 'black', 'john' and many names...
- I want to for loop the `names` package directory, and package `tom.jar,jerry.jar,black.jar...`

I use `ant` for now, An ant target call another target works well and simple. 
But this project need migrate to gradle

- I tried to use task call other task, but always got `could not find method with arguments []`
- I tried to define my own task class to resolve the error, but my owner task class could not use the `Jar` task.

PlZ, anybody can help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the classes inside each package (tom, jerry, black, ...) independent of each other, then the easiest way would be to create [subprojects](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/) (modules) for each of these, and put only the corresponding packages into each module. If you do this, and apply the java plugin to each module, then you don't need to write any special tasks with filtering, just run the jar task for the whole project, and you're basically done.

If there are dependencies between the packages, (but not circular) then you just have to make the modules depend on each other.

Is there any particular reason for keeping these packages in the same module?

Comment: uh....I have many names under this package, over than 50... so subproject is not a good way...

Comment: I've created a simple example [project](https://github.com/balazsbanyai/example-stackoverflow-gradle-create-multi-jar) to demonstrate the problem, and added an [implementation](https://github.com/balazsbanyai/example-stackoverflow-gradle-create-multi-jar/blob/master/build.gradle#L38) that should does what you want.
If you run the jarAll task, it will run all the package-specific tasks. Nevertheless, I think breaking the project into modules would make more sense, even though it has a significant overhead in the beginning.